# How do I get more info from api reactjs & axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

If I want to get more info from the players, for example last name, height, weight. How do I do that? Here is the api:

{"id":237,"first_name":"LeBron","height_feet":6,"height_inches":8,"last_name":"James","position":"F","team":{"id":14,"abbreviation":"LAL","city":"Los Angeles","conference":"West","division":"Pacific","full_name":"Los Angeles Lakers","name":"Lakers"},"weight_pounds":250}

```js
const App = () => {
  const[playerName, setPlayerName] = useState([]);
  const[playerName1, setPlayerName1] = useState([]);
  const[playerName2, setPlayerName2] = useState([]);
  const[playerPic, setPlayerPic] = useState([]);
  const[playerPic1, setPlayerPic1] = useState([]);
  const[playerPic2, setPlayerPic2] = useState([]);


  const fetchData = () => {
    const playerAPI = 'https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players/237'
    const playerAPI1 = 'https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players/47'
    const playerAPI2 = 'https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players/237'
    const playerPic = 'https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players/james/lebron'
    const playerPic1 = 'https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players/bird/jabari'
    const playerPic2 = 'https://nba-players.herokuapp.com/players/jackson/Demetrius'

    const getNBAPlayer = axios.get(playerAPI)
    const getNBAPlayer1 = axios.get(playerAPI1)
    const getNBAPlayer2 = axios.get(playerAPI2)
    const getPlayerPic = axios.get(playerPic)
    const getPlayerPic1 = axios.get(playerPic1)
    const getPlayerPic2 = axios.get(playerPic2)

    axios.all([getNBAPlayer, getNBAPlayer1, getNBAPlayer2, getPlayerPic, getPlayerPic1, getPlayerPic2]).then(
      axios.spread((...allData) => {
        const allDataPlayer = allData[0].data.first_name
        const allDataPlayer1 = allData[1].data.first_name;
        const allDataPlayer2 = allData[2].data.first_name;
        const getNBAPlayerPic = allData[3].config.url;
        const getNBAPlayerPic1 = allData[4].config.url;
        const getNBAPlayerPic2 = allData[5].config.url;
        
        setPlayerName(allDataPlayer)
        setPlayerName1(allDataPlayer1)
        setPlayerName2(allDataPlayer2)
        setPlayerPic(getNBAPlayerPic)
        setPlayerPic1(getNBAPlayerPic1)
        setPlayerPic2(getNBAPlayerPic2)
      })
    )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        <li>
          Player name is: {playerName}
          <img src={playerPic} alt="img" />
        </li>
        <li>
          Player name is: {playerName1}
          <img src={playerPic1} alt="img" />
        </li>
        <li>
          Player name is: {playerName2}
          <img src={playerPic2} alt="img" />
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What kind of more information you are trying to get from that api? https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players/237 this url gives all the information for the player.

Comment: Yes, but how do I write it out, I have this one for first name "const allDataPlayer = allData[0].data.first_name" how can I add last name, height, weight to the list element?

Answer (score 1):

You are using too many states. It's not clean and readable code plus that's a complicated logic to fetch the players one by one. Instead of doing it you can set the whole data to one state and use map() function to transform your state into a list. I recommend you to read the documentation of ReactJS about this topic. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

I created a project for you. It shows how you can manage the state so please check it. You might get the idea. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8acmxv?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is exactly what I wanted!! I tried your code, and if I want to add one more player by ID a added like this "const playersId = [14, 47, 71, 200];" but I dont get any result or if I change the id to another player I dont get that result either... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because api gets a parameter ?per_page= and ?page= . The url i used is just returning first page. And still this is manual logic that is not good practice. You can add a search and pagination functionality.

Comment: Check the url again https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8acmxv . I did simple pagination and added search url for unique player. You can add your own logic.